# Compiler Construction - Follow set of a grammar

Tags: compiler-construction

I have following grammar

```
E -> TX
X -> +E
     |epsilon
T -> intY
     | (E)
Y -> *T
     | epsilon
```

Is the below Follow set is correct for above grammar?

```
   E = {$, )}
   X = {$, )}
   T = {int, (, $}
   Y = {int, (, $}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***First***

```
First(E) -> {int, (}
First(X) -> {+, epl}
First(T) -> {int, (}
First(Y) -> {*, epl}
```

***Follow***

```
Follow(E) -> {$, )}
Follow(X) -> {Follow(E)}
Follow(T) -> {First(X) - epl, Follow(E)} -> {+, $, )} 
Follow(Y) -> {Follow(T)}
```

Why Follow(E) in Follow(T)? because First(X) has epsilon
    ->which give us E -> T production

Answer (score 0):

For the following grammar:

```
E -> TX

X -> +E |epsilon

T -> intY| (E)

Y -> *T| epsilon
```

Calculating the First of the set

> FIRST(E) = FIRST(T) - epsilon U FIRST(X)
>
> ={int, (, +, epsilon }
>
> FIRST(X) = FIRST(+E) - epsilon U epsilon
>
> ={+, epsilon}
>
> FIRST(T) = FIRST(intY) - epsilon U FIRST( (E) )
>
> ={int, ( }
>
> FIRST(Y) = FIRST(*T) - epsilon U epsilon
>
> ={*, epsilon}

Calculating of FOLLOW set

> Follow(E) -> {$,)}
>
> Follow(X) -> {$,)}
>
> Follow(T) -> {+,$,)}
>
> Follow(Y) -> {+,$,)}